# Abrir Form2 e Fechar Form1, tornando Form2 o principal (sem deixar ele invisível)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Olá, tenho o seguinte problema:
Tenho os Form's `FrmLogin` e `FrmSistema`. Quando o usuário logar no `FrmLogin` eu abro o `FrmSitema`, torno o `FrmSitema` o `FormPrincipal`, e fecho o `FrmLogin`.

OBS: Não quero esconder o `FrmLogin`, como vi aqui muitos comentando:

```
this.hide();
FrmLogin.Show();
```

Pois pensa bem, se o usuário ficar clicando em Logar e em deslogar vai ficar cheio de forms invisiveis usando memória atoa, não é esse meu objetivo, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Já tentou destruir o form quando ele fechar. Assim não terá que se preocupara com a memoria...
Agora... não vi sentido o usuário logado querer logar novamente com o sistema aberto?

Comment: Olá Edu, Obrigado por responder.
Se ele logar, vai exibir o FRMPrincipal, no FRm principal tem a opção dele deslogar e logar com outro usuário.
Se um funcionário utilizar o programa e ao final do seu turno sair e deslogar e não fechar vai abrir outra tela e assim por diante.
Como assim destruir o Form, poderia me dar detalhes e postar o código?

Comment: Não entendo de c# mais deve ter o método `destructor` para liberar o forme de login da memoria... 
veja [docs.microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve mudar a forma de como está inciando sua aplicação. Considere inciá-la pelo form principal e então chame o form de login.
Após a verificação do usuário/senha, retorne um resultado positivo, case seja negativo, o form principal será fechado.
Utilizei a propriedade `Login` para escrever no form principal o nome de usuário digitado no frm de login.

Veja:
**FrmPrincipal**
Função que valida o FrmLogin

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Retorna verdadeira se o login/senha forem válidos
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool LoginValido() {
        //Somente retorna OK se o login/senha forem válidos
        bool loginValido = false;
        FrmLogin frmLogin = new FrmLogin();
        loginValido = frmLogin.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK;

        Login = frmLogin.Login; //Preenche a propriedade do form principal

        return loginValido;
    }
```

Este é no `load` do form, só deixará carregar o FrmPrincipal caso o login seja válido

```
    private void FrmPrincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!LoginValido())
            Close();
        lblLogin.Text = Login;
    }
```

Para trocar de usuário, como você citou

```
    private void BtnTrocarUsuario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (LoginValido()) {
            lblLogin.Text = Login;
            AplicaDiretivas(Login);
        }
    }
```

**No FrmLogin** não tem segredo, ao validar o usuário e senha, o resultado da janela deverá ser o OK.

```
    private void BtnLogar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //
        // Verificar se login/senha são válidos
        //
        if (login/senha for válido) {
            Login = txtLogin.Text;
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Login/senha inválidos", "Atenção!");
        }
    }
```

Se o usuário cancelar ou fechar a janela, o resultado será sempre negativo, isso fechará o form principal

```
    private void BtnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Close();
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado, da pra fazer dessa forma :D